# Statement: " There must be at least one statement in the executable part in main function."

Tags: c

My textbook mentions: There must be at least one statement in the executable part of main function.

1)

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(){ int c; }
```

2)

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(){ int c; c=0; }
```

The above two codes result in runtime error.

3)

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(){
int c; c=5; printf("%d",c); }
```

The above code runs fine. What is the possible reason?

Comment: _The above two codes result in runtime error_............ o.O Best thing: get rid of your book. Moreover `void main()` ---> `int main ( void )`

Comment: `int c;` is not a statement. It is a definition. However, `void main()` is an invalid signature on a hosted environment. And follow @LPs advice: get rid of that book, it tells nonsense.

Comment: What runtime error do you get?

Comment: Which compiler are you using ?

Comment: `int main() {}` is the only thing required for a C program to run. No statements, no nothing.

Comment: @DeiDei: `int main()` is an obsolescence feature. Use prototype-signatures for functions: `int main(void)`. C is not C++.

Comment: In C, to get the program to do anything useful, you must have either an executable statement (a function call) or a variable definition with initialization where the initialization calls a function.  However, a minimal program that doesn't do anything useful need not have any statements or definitions in `main()`.

Comment: Would `int main() {;}` count? ;)

Answer (score 3):

First,

> 1     The function called at program startup is named `main`. The implementation declares no
> prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of `int` and with no
> parameters:
>
> ```
>     int main(void) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or with two parameters (referred to here as `argc` and **`argv`**, though any names may be
> used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared):
>     `int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }`
> or equivalent;<sup>10)</sup> or in some other implementation-defined manner.

<sup>[C 2011 Online Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), §5.1.2.2.1 Program Startup</sup>

Unless your compiler documentation specifically lists it as a valid signature, using `void main()` leads to *undefined behavior*, which may be where your runtime errors are coming from.

Secondly, the current C standard does not require that `main` contain any executable statements.